# Why does table throws exception when contents of TextField in any of its column header cells grow larger than page height?

Tags: jasper-reports, infinite-loop

Jasperreports Studio throws a runtime error during preview when the contents of a table cell (Text field) is large. Important thing here is that the Text field need to have its **Stretch With Overflow property set to True**

Following is the exception thrown:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Infinite loop creating new page due to column header overflow.
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.fillReport(ReportController.java:536)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.access$17(ReportController.java:511)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController$1.run(ReportController.java:429)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Infinite loop creating new page due to column header overflow.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:534)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:154)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:615)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:822)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This issue can be reproduced in multiple ways but I am using simplest scenario. I have attached simple jrxml file for reference. I have used a table with empty data set. I have used Text Field expression to display data. I have set isStretchWithOverflow to true.

**JRXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Table_Based" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="66519d71-4f27-4833-9a1d-c9b72e811f0c">
<property name="template.engine" value="tabular_template"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
<style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true"/>
<style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
<style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Transparent">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<style name="Table">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="bcc32bbf-2279-43e0-8149-66ee3e913b5e">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
</subDataset>
<subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="13d74fad-eb9b-446f-a81d-55b8cf6ea0db">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
</subDataset>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<title>
    <band height="113" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Title" x="270" y="0" width="263" height="62" uuid="a080d2ca-6207-4d8e-87c9-d3b61fb495a9"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Report Title]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="303" y="62" width="196" height="22" uuid="0d849401-f944-4163-9df0-f69408a0618a"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Report SubTitle]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<summary>
    <band height="112" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.grid.JSSGridBagLayout"/>
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="112" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="f3767496-0434-4f42-862b-5839d580e423">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="05c4f663-c370-4c53-b332-ae9dfb9590e0"/>
                <jr:column width="170" uuid="a3e3c62f-3558-42a1-a701-ad31853970a9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="170" height="30" uuid="a5ddd2d9-992d-41d2-a7d0-4cc7ec29350b"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="20"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Number]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ElementGroupHeight" x="0" y="0" width="170" height="30" uuid="b4f24d97-8dbe-42e8-81a8-34fb336eabef"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="40" rowSpan="1"/>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="173" uuid="e2eaa014-ebfd-4795-b752-476ca2fa8f0b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                    <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="173" height="30" uuid="b80ae7ce-3491-45cd-963d-8638f03a3891"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <font size="20"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Text]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:tableHeader>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="173" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="a2647f94-9054-4efd-904e-0850eead4cdf"/>
                            <textElement>
                                <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[UPPER("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm")]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                    <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="40">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</summary>
```

In similarly scenario Jasperreports server throws a different runtime exception:
It appears to be some kind of bug. Any help would be great help.

```
2018-09-21 17:03:26,667 ERROR RenderViewExceptionInterceptor,http-nio-8080-exec-8:55 - Internal server error occurred. Please contact your system administrator.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.util.TableUtil.getAllColumns(TableUtil.java:162)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.json.HeaderToolbarElementJsonHandler.getColumnGroupsData(HeaderToolbarElementJsonHandler.java:832)
at net.sf.jasperreports.components.headertoolbar.json.HeaderToolbarElementJsonHandler.getJsonFragment(HeaderToolbarElementJsonHandler.java:237)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JsonExporter.exportGenericElement(JsonExporter.java:487)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **redesign** your report.

Currently you want a column header on each page, but your column header does not fit on page, so what happens is.

1. Create column header (because start of table or new page)
2. Break to new page (since it does not fit).
3. Go to 1 since new page.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Infinite loop creating new page due to column header overflow.

Your solution can be all from making text smaller, column larger or truncate text so that it fits in page.

Comment: Thanks @PetterFriberg. The issue is that, I have some data which will force a cell to occupy two pages. I have **corrected** the above JRXML, to display data in **detail cell** . A **NullpointerException** now getting thrown.

Comment: @AmitWalvekar sorry but you need to pass a new question, If you change the current question my answer does not have sense anymore

Comment: @PeterFriberg, I can certainly create a new question if you insist, but the issue remains same. If the content of table detail cell or header cell is large to not fit in one page, a runtime exception is thrown. Your solution unfortunately may not work in my actual code since I have multiple dynamic columns and large data. Again, thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @AmitWalvekar yes please post a new question, because your first issue was a design issue, instead the Nullpointer issue (with good design) is probably a bug in latest JasperSoftStudio v6.6.0 (I can run that report in old version, removing the non supported stretchType). You can ping me here if you like me to investigate exactly if it is a bug and what workaround can be available.